# Firebase physical database location

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently planning on using the firebase database for commercial use, but I have hit a bottleneck.
I live in Denmark and it's not allowed to distribute personal data such as the users address or mail to countries beyond EU.
So I was wondering if the Firebase database in Europe only contains European data and does not export the information to a *master database* in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: 2023-02-27**

Since it's a very answer, I need to provide an update.

Nowadays, you can choose the location of the Realtime Database even in Europe:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations

---

Many citizens  (especially from the EU) are concerned about where their data is located. As I read on the internet back in 2015, at [Google DevFest in Amsterdam](https://developers.google.com/events/5041274762035200/) where Frank van Puffelen presented Firebase, it was said that the datacentre in the US **but** they were planning to open one in Europe.

Also, in 2016 Kato Richardson commented in a similar [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/1PfVoebJBw4) that the servers are located at that time in `Central US`.

Since then, I didn't hear anything regarding Firebase servers in the EU. I'm also hoping they will open a data center in the EU but for now, we need to wait. Will see in the near future what happens.

Comment: I know this might be hypothetical, but if there was an EU server, how could i ensure that the information doesn't get out of europa?

Comment: When the time will come, we hope that the term and conditions regarding data policy will ensure you that actually your data will remain in EU and they will not export our information to a master database in the US.